# RewriteRule not working for one specific case

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm banging my head on the wall with this one. I have a rewrite rule in my htaccess file which works for all urls but one. Here's the line

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ content.php?linkid=$1 [L]
```

And the complete htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^contact-us content.php?linkid=contact-us [L,R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ content.php?linkid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ media.php?news=$1&pgNo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^news-details/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ media-detail.php?news_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^services-list/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ services-list-new.php?services_list=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^specialities/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ speciality-listing.php?speciality=$1&pgNo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^services-details/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ services.php?speciality_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^treatment-detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ treatment-detail.php?treatment_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^testimonial/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ testimonials.php?testimonial=$1&pgNo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^testimonial-detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ testimonial-detail.php?test_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^photo-gallery-detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ photo-gallery-detail.php?photo_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^media/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ media.php?media=$1&pgNo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^media-detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ media-detail.php?media_detail=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^doctor-profile/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ doctor.php?doc_short=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^make-an-appointment/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ make-an-appointmen.php?appointment_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^current-openings/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ current-openings.php?current_opening=$1&pgNo=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

So this works for `domain.com/privacy-policy` which goes to `domain.com/content.php?linkid=privacy-policy` and a few others like testimonials, services, career etc

BUT, it doesn't work for contact-us, i.e. `domain.com/contact-us`

I've even tried the hard coded version above which is the commented line above. Any ideas guys?

**EDIT:**
I've tried using the url `domain.com/content.php?linkid=contact-us`which works correctly but `domain.com/contact-us` gives me the error **The requested URL /contact-us was not found on this server.**.

I've also discovered another url that's not working and it is `domain.com/media/list/1` which says **The requested URL /media.html/list/1 was not found on this server.** I don't know where it's getting media.html from. There was a file named media.html in the file structure so I removed that and the link started working. That's not the case with contact-us though.

Comment: It's not a real directory. This website loads all pages by redirecting them to content.php with a unique value of `linkid`. I don't think I have anything in Apache config but I have no way of knowing from just cpanel, right? I've also entered the url `domain.com/linkid=contact-us` which does load the page. It's just the rewrite that's not working

Comment: That is weird but looking at your code these rules are not the reason of `/contact-us` not working. Are you getting 404 for `/contact-us`?

Comment: Try changing `Options` line to `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Comment: Oh Man, It worked!! Thank you so much. I'll go read on FollowSymlinks now :D

Comment: Problem is actually presence of `MultiViews`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating above comments into an answer as it might help someone with similar problems.

You need to disable `MultiViews` options to make it work.

So just change your `Options` line this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by [`Apache's content negotiation module`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.